# How to detect current keyboard writing language in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, keyboard, windows-phone

I wanna programmatically set a TextBlock flow direction depended on user current writing landuage(**NOT phone language**). for example if keyboard is set to Arabic, RightToLeft and for English, LeftToRight. Is there anyway to get current keyboard language in windows phone 8 ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a darn good question.

It doesn't seem to be exposed in Windows Phone 8.

I found this here [Font and language configuration support for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202920%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

> Text input
>
> The selection of languages for which a phone has preinstalled keyboards and input
> method UIs is dependent on which market a phone is sold in. At any time the user
> can download and use a keyboard for any of the 50 supported phone client UI
> languages. The language of the keyboard, which determines the characters that
> are written to a TextBox control, is not programmatically available to an app.

It's interesting to note that this IS available for Windows Store Apps.

See [Windows.Globalization.Language.currentInputMethodLanguageTag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.language.currentinputmethodlanguagetag.aspx).

Oh Microsoft...